# Creating 5 reports from top 5 rows of filtered table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to coding macros. I've been pulling a lot from this site to get me up to speed and it's helped a ton.

I'm trying to create one report for each row of data for the top five rows of visible data in a filtered table. I've seen several kind of close examples listed, but I haven't figured out how to integrate them into a functioning product. Help getting me over the final hurdle would be much appreciated.

My table has a header row from A2:T2, so I need to pull from the five rows below the header using the xlCellTypeVisible so only the visible rows are selected. The length of the table varies daily but it's never shorter than 150 rows.

Here's the data code I'm trying to create a new sheet, and pull from the first row of the table:

```
' Create new sheet for report
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 

' Add Part number, Description & Company to header

' Part Number
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("K3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
Range("A2").Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
' Part description
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("L3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A3")
' Customer
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("G3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("F3")

' Add info from Variance Data tab

' Work Center
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("C3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A6")
' Work Order
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("H3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("C6")
' Task
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("D3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("D6")
' Seq #
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("I3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("E6")
' Qty
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("M3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("F6")

' Est Hrs
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("O3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B8")
' Act. Hrs
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("Q3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B9")
' Var. Hrs
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("S3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B10")
' Est Cost
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("P3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("E8")
' Act. Cost
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("R3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("E9")
' Var. Cost
Sheets("Variance Data").Range("T3").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("E10")

ActiveSheet.Name = Range("A2").Value
```

How do I change this so I  loop this to create five sheets, one for each row of data from the main data sheet titled "Variance Data" and fill in to the new sheet?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need any adjustments let me know. Remember that if you want to run the macro twice, you need to remove newly created sheets, because trying to create sheets with the same name will cause an error.

The below code works if assigned for freshly created ActiveX command button (gets a default name CommandButton1), no matter which of your sheets you have the button in.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim v_data As Variant
Dim mainsheet As String
Dim thelastrow As Long, visibleRowsCount As Long, arrayRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

'disable screen updating on code execution for faster performance and no screen flickering
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'name of your data sheet
mainsheet = "Variance Data"

'create an array from sheet data, starting range is defined in code, last row is the last row containing data in your sheet
'only visible rows are taken
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(mainsheet)
    thelastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    v_data = .Range("a3:t" & thelastrow)

'works for 5 top visible rows - create sheets and populate them with data from array
Do Until visibleRowsCount = 5 Or arrayRow = UBound(v_data)
    arrayRow = arrayRow + 1
    If Not Rows(arrayRow + 2).Hidden Then
        visibleRowsCount = visibleRowsCount + 1
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "Report" & visibleRowsCount
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report" & visibleRowsCount)
            'Cell value of your new report worksheet = value from data array
            .Range("a5").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 5) 'take data from 5th column of the current row
            .Range("b3").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 1) 'take data from 1st column of the current row
            .Range("d3").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 1) 'take the same data from 1st column of the current row and put in a different cell
        End With
    End If
Loop

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Actually I forgot a vital part of the code to make it work properly for hidden rows, I changed the code from: v_data = .Range("a3:t" & thelastrow) to v_data = .Range("a3:t" & thelastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Comment: I'm busy with another major project, but I'll try the code as soon as possible.Is there a reason you use Option Explicit and make the sub private?

Comment: Option Explicit forces you to declare all variables, what is good if you forget to declare one or make a typing error. Option Base 1 changes lower bound of an array from default 0 to 1, so the in the example above sheet row numbers correspond to array rows. Private sub is default for Command Button and there is no need to use public.

Comment: Now, it's stopping at the first hidden row rather than skipping over it to five visible rows. so if arrayRow = 3 and the third row is hidden it generates two reports and stops. After a series of test MsgBoxes, I'm pretty sure the code that's stopping it early is the UBound test code.    'if there are more than 5 visible rows - create 5 reports, if 5 or less  - create reports from all visible rows
        If UBound(v_data) > 5 Then
            thelastvisible = 5
        Else
            thelastvisible = UBound(v_data)
        End If         Should I change it to a countif loop for visible rows?

Comment: Thanks for feedback, unfortunately it appears that arrays don't do well with hidden cells detection, so I changed the code a lot, It now takes all data into an array and checks which rows are hidden. I tested it on worksheet with hidden rows and it works.

Comment: I truly thank you for sticking with me to help get this right. I think we are really close. I created a test sheet  with A1 through T1 on the top row of the data and down to A14 through T14 and tested with different hidden row combinations. The revised program creates reports for the top five rows regardless if they are hidden or not. For this section of code 'arrayRow = arrayRow + 1
        If Not Rows(arrayRow + 2).Hidden Then' did you intend to do +1 and +2 ? Not sure if that is causing to not skip hidden.

Comment: I made an array from data range v_data = .Range("a3:t" & thelastrow) and rest of the code also assumes that first row with data is a third row. If You want it to work starting from 1st row, the code should be changed in 2 places: `.Range("a3:t" & thelastrow)` to `.Range("a1:t" & thelastrow)` and `Rows(arrayRow + 2).Hidden` to `Rows(arrayRow).Hidden`. An expression `arrayRow = arrayRow + 1` inside a Do loop is just a replacement of For loop, for the first time loop runs, arrayRow value will be 0+1=1, next time 1+1=2 etc.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear. I meant the first row of data on row 3 of the spreadsheet. :-) Yeah, the If Not Rows(arrayRow +2).Hidden confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Cells(). You can use Cells(i, j).value to read and write values where i and j are numerical and represent row number and column number. You can then enclose your code in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the current code I have thanks to Ryszard:

```
    ' If you need any adjustments let me know. Remember that if you want to run the macro twice, you need to remove newly created sheets, because trying to create sheets with the same name will cause an error.

 Option Explicit
 Option Base 1

Sub TestVarRpt() ' Changed to Macro versus ActiveX button, personal preference

Dim v_data As Variant
Dim mainsheet As String
Dim thelastrow As Long, visibleRowsCount As Long, arrayRow As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet

'disable screen updating on code execution for faster performance and no screen flickering
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'name of your data sheet
mainsheet = "Sheet1" ' **** CHANGE TO "Variance Report" on successful run ****


'create an array from sheet data, starting range is defined in code, last row is the last row containing data in your sheet
'only visible rows are taken
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(mainsheet)
thelastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
v_data = .Range("a3:t" & thelastrow)

'works for 5 top visible rows - create sheets and populate them with data from array
Do Until visibleRowsCount = 5 Or arrayRow = UBound(v_data)
    arrayRow = arrayRow + 1
    If Not Rows(arrayRow + 2).Hidden Then
        visibleRowsCount = visibleRowsCount + 1
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "Report" & visibleRowsCount
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report" & visibleRowsCount)


  ' Part Information
        '   Part Number
         '   Sheets("Variance Data").Range("K" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
             .Range("a2").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 11) 'take data from 11th column of the current row

        '   Part description
            'Sheets("Variance Data").Range("L" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A3")
             .Range("a3").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 12) 'take data from 12th column of the current row

        '   Customer
            'Sheets("Variance Data").Range("G" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("F3")
             .Range("f3").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 7) 'take data from 7th column of the current row

        '   Work Center
            'Sheets("Variance Data").Range("C" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A6")
             .Range("a6").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 3) 'take data from 3rd column of the current row

        '   Work Order
            'Sheets("Variance Data").Range("H" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("C6")
             .Range("c6").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 8) 'take data from 8th column of the current row

        '   Task
            'Sheets("Variance Data").Range("D" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("D6")
             .Range("d6").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 4) 'take data from 5th column of the current row

        '   Seq #
            'Sheets("Variance Data").Range("I" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("E6")
             .Range("e6").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 9) 'take data from 9th column of the current row

        '   Qty
            'Sheets("Variance Data").Range("M" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("F6")
             .Range("f6").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 13) 'take data from 13th column of the current row

   ' Hours
        '   Est Hrs
            'Sheets("Variance Data").Range("O" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B8")
             .Range("b8").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 15) 'take data from 15th column of the current row

        '   Act. Hrs
            'Sheets("Variance Data").Range("Q" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B9")
             .Range("b9").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 17) 'take data from 17th column of the current row

        '   Var. Hrs
            'Sheets("Variance Data").Range("S" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B10")
             .Range("b10").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 19) 'take data from 19th column of the current row

   ' Cost
        '   Est Cost
            'Sheets("Variance Data").Range("P" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("E8")
             .Range("e8").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 16) 'take data from 16th column of the current row

        '   Act. Cost
            'Sheets("Variance Data").Range("R" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("E9")
             .Range("e9").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 18) 'take data from 18th column of the current row

        '   Var. Cost
            'Sheets("Variance Data").Range("T" & cnt + 2).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("E10")
             .Range("e10").Value = v_data(arrayRow, 20) 'take data from 5th column of the current row

            ws.Name = v_data(arrayRow, 11)


        End With
    End If
Loop

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The result is it creates reports for the first five rows regardless if they are hidden or not. I'm not following the logic of this code so it might be the problem.

```
    Do Until visibleRowsCount = 5 Or arrayRow = UBound(v_data)
    arrayRow = arrayRow + 1 ' Increment array row by one
    If Not Rows(arrayRow + 2).Hidden Then ' If the two rows after current row isn't hidden then
        visibleRowsCount = visibleRowsCount + 1 ' add one to the visible count
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `If Not Rows(arrayRow + 2).Hidden` means checking if a row isn't hidden (is visible). `Rows(arrayRow + 2)` will return 3rd row of the sheet (meaning 1st row with data) for arrayRow =1 (1st array row).

Comment: By the way if you want to use value from column K to create sheet's name, You should remove `ws.Name = v_data(arrayRow, 11)` and change code in upper part of the loop to `ws.Name = v_data(arrayRow, 11) With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(v_data(arrayRow, 11))`

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm confused that the Do Loop isn't filtering out the hidden rows. The If Not statement SHOULD work, but for some reason it's not for me... Is there a way to upload a spreadsheet, so you can see what the macro is doing for me?

Comment: You can upload file to some server and post a link in a comment.

Comment: Finally got it to work! Thanks so much, Ryszard! You're a life saver!